# Anchor Tagging Documents Added After Creating Draft

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to apply anchor tagging to a document added after a draft envelope has been created from a template.

This works if an existing document (from the template) is present and it contains the anchor tag. Adding the second document and setting `doc.ApplyAnchorTabs` to `true` is all I needed to do.

However, if an existing document does not contain the anchor tag (bearing in mind you have to set `tab.AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent` to `true`), it does not apply the tags to any documents added after the draft has been created.

I'm pretty sure it is a bug, thoughts?